# Javascript convert time to CET

Tags: javascript, html, date, time

I am new to Javascript.
I want to convert my local time to CET time zone.

I found method to convert localtime to UTC but, I need to direct covert this to CET timezone.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Since you know the offset from your local time to UTC simply add or subtract according to the difference.